# remove blur from textarea on file upload html | css | javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page where I want the text to be appear clear not blur

when I upload file the text is read from file and displayed on TextArea but the text appears to be blur

The concept I am using is when I type some specific keyword if that specific keyword matches when a type in the textarea then it appears in a different color like keyword "connected"  if I type this in textarea then apperas green this is how my function is defined

**Issue :** when I take the text from file, the text is displayed on my textarea but appears blur how to fix that blur

**work with this file and see gives blur content**
could you please upload this text file and see (sample text file) link : sendspace.com/file/67ge9n you may get to see blur content as shown in image sendspace.com/file/r25qme

```js
const color = {
  "connected successfully": "green",
  "connected": "green",
  "connection failure": "red"
};
let textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
let colorsArea = document.querySelector(".colors");
let backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop");

// Event listeners.

textArea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  colorsArea.innerHTML = applyColors(textArea.value);
});

textArea.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  backdrop.scrollTop = textArea.scrollTop;
});

function applyColors(text) {
  let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(color).join("|"), "gi");

  return text.replace(re, function(m) {
    let c = color[m.toLowerCase()];
    return `<spam style="color:${c}">${m}</spam>`;
  });
}



function rdata() {
  var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
    textArea.value = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container,
.backdrop,
#myTextArea {
  font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 48%;
  height: 250px;
}

#myTextArea {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  /* i change it to red , u can change to any color u want */
  resize: none;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.colors {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input id="myFile" type="file" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="backdrop">
        <div class="colors">
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea id="myTextArea" onclick="rdata();"></textarea>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your text isn't blurred you have 2 containers with a position absolute on top of each other. When you type the same text pops up on both with a slight offset giving it a blurred affect. The 2 containers are backdrop and mytextarea with a position of absolute making them appear on top of one another.

Comment: how do i fix it @Jonny

Comment: you can change the position to relative to see what im talking about that will unstack the 2 containers.  you will have to play with it to position them where you want

Answer (score 0):

its not blur ? ur code is correct

[image]

Comment: could you please upload this text file and see (sample text file) link : https://www.sendspace.com/file/67ge9n    you may get to see blur content as shown in image https://www.sendspace.com/file/r25qme